# JavaScript Math formula

Tags: javascript, math

I was given the following Excel formula to calculate the french system interest of a loan:

```
=+G15*B15/(1-(1+G15)^(-H15))
```

Where:

```
G15 = 1.33%
B15 = importe
H15 = plazo
```

As I usually have issues with the order of what gets solved I break up the formula in small peaces. This is what I've got

```
// user input
var importe = parseFloat($('#importe_prestamo').val());
var plazo = parseFloat($('#plazo_prestamo').val());

//formula
var formula1 = 0.0133 * importe;
var parentesis1 = parseFloat(1 + importe);
var potencia = Math.pow(parentesis1,plazo);
var parentgde = 1 - potencia;
var totalcount = formula1 / parentgde;
console.log(totalcount);
```

I'm entering 10000 in "importe" and "144" in plazo but get `totalcount = 0` since "var potencia" returns "Infinity"

I'have been doing all kinds for this formulas for weeks for this projects that I get confused of so much information and I'm now clueless how to continue solving this formula. Any pointer would be great. Thanks

Comment: You miss a minus: `var potencia = Math.pow(parentesis1,plazo);`

Comment: Think about what you're doing: importe+1 = 10001 and you're raising it to the 144 power.  That means a number like 10^148.  What computer can represent a number so large?  Compare that to the number of atoms in the universe: http://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/

Comment: Im driving in blind mode here, I get nightmares about this project with all the formulas I've been dealing with. I read my code tens of times and didn't find out I was missing a 1-, I needed a fresh mind on this. Thanks Gandaro, you want to post it as an anser so I mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss a minus in that line:

```
var potencia = Math.pow(parentesis1,plazo);
```

it should be

```
var potencia = Math.pow(parentesis1, -plazo);
```

Although you could write the whole formula in one line…

Edit: And how? ;-)

```
var G15 = 0.0133, B15 = importe, H15 = plazo;
var total = G15 * B15 / (1 - pow(1 + G15, -H15));
```

Comment: agree... one liner would be nicer :D

Comment: any idea why given G=15, B=10000, H=144 and 0.1325 instead of 0.133 in excel the formula equals to 155.93 and in javascript 132.5 ?

Comment: Would you please say use the names you used before?  In your formula G[15] is 0.0133, which you want to be 0.1325, but you say G=15.

Answer (score 1):

according to the formula...

```
var parentesis1 = parseFloat(1 + importe);
```

should be

```
var parentesis1 = parseFloat(1 + 0.0133);
```

and as mentioned you are also missing -.

Comment: Right! I missed that one. ;-)